# Show classified images in tensorboard with keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection, tensorboard

I saw a nice function of tensorboard in the [google post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine) announcing their object detection API. They show classifications of exemplary images while training:

[image: classified image in tensorboard]

Is it possible to adjust the callbacks in keras (https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) to reproduce this?

Answer (score -2):

To do so you need to use the appropriate tensorboard summaries, just as in the demo code for the cloud example.

Comment: Where do you see the tensorboard summaries in the demo code?

Comment: search for "summary"?

Comment: Then I am probably looking at the wrong code. I could neither find "summary"  in the blog post I linked above (https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine) nor in the mentioned sample config files (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs). The only trace I found is the method "visualize_detection_results" in  eval_util.py in the same repo. Is that what you are refering to? Your answer would be more helpful with a concrete reference or example.

Comment: I don't see the code which is generating the tensorflow graph used for training in either of the links you sent.

Comment: Then what code are you referring to in your answer when you say "[...]  just as in the demo code for the cloud example"?

Comment: I assumed there was some graph building code in there somewhere.